# Is Jay-Z personally doing negotiations, contract details, etc., or he is delegating as a sport agent?

Tags: finances, international-sports

I read that Jay-Z, the popular entertainer, gave up his interest in the New York Knicks so that he could represent Kevin Durant.  Is there any evidence that he is personally doing negotiations, contract details, etc., or is he delegating?  What educational training, if any, does he have for this, and has he signed any other atheletes?  If he's good and he's serious, it sounds like a solid Plan B when his star goes down with the entertainment world.

Comment: Can someone with the rights add a tag for "agents"?

Comment: I don't know all the details, but IIRC he has hired a couple of superstar agents from major agencies. Many of whom brought big clients with them.

Comment: @BruceJames ask about it on [meta](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `finances` are good enough for now. `management` would include but won't be limited to agents, but as Nicholas V. says, ask on meta and we'll flesh something out.

Comment: @waxeagle Is IIRC the name of Jay-Z's enterprise?

Comment: @BruceJames no, it's an internet acronym for If I recall correctly. The agency is ummm Rocnation

Comment: I don't find a good close reason that applies to this question, but I don't think this is a good fit for the site... particularly with the new title (which makes it at least sort of opinion based, so I'm picking that).

Comment: @Joe Does new title edit make it acceptable or not? I answered this question as it was unanswered for 3 years.

Comment: The new title is ... long.  Very long.  This isn't really ideal for a title.  It's better than Philip's title, in my opinion (as that was not something that was answerable as it gets to the inner motivations of a person) but this one is very long and thus not great either.  I don't know, maybe this question ultimately is one that's okay for this site, I just don't find it very "sports" related.

Comment: Maybe "Is Jay-Z Acting as an Agent?" or something simple like that.  Though really the question could use an entire overhaul or maybe just a new question, given it's horribly out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any evidence that he is personally doing negotiations, contract details, etc., or is he delegating?

Since [Jay-Z is licensed to be an NBA and MLB agent](http://hiphopdx.com/news/id.24393/title.jay-z-now-a-licensed-nba-mlb-agent#). He may have done negotiations, contract details, etc. But at beginning, [he partnered up](http://www.totalprosports.com/2014/11/17/the-12-clients-of-jay-zs-roc-nation-sports/) with CAA and NFL superagent Tom Condon. [Now the agency is looking to hire agents](https://www.si.com/more-sports/2014/10/20/roc-nation-jay-z-sports-agency-hiring) and buy their agencies and hire some. so he personally doesn't have to negotiate.

Also from [complex.com](http://www.complex.com/sports/2013/06/jay-z-licensed-nba-agent-roc-nation-sports) article:

> Jay-Z is officially licensed to be an NBA agent. So he will be able to sign new clients and negotiate on their behalf moving forward.

And this [hiphopdx.com](http://hiphopdx.com/news/id.34684/title.jay-z-lands-70-million-deal-for-dez-bryant#) article will help clarifying few things.

> The [Dallas Cowboys](http://www.dallascowboys.com/video/2015/07/16/secret-audio-jerry-calls-congratulate-dez) released a video of team owner Jerry Jones congratulating Bryant and explaining how he worked out a deal with his agent.
>
> “My hats off to you,” Jones tells Bryant. “You did a good job associating yourself with Jay Z. He’s wonderful. I spent hours with him last night and it was great, thinks a lot of you and I do too.”

[Roc Nation Sports](http://rocnation.com/about/), is the agency founded by rapper Jay-Z.

> Roc Nation Sports’ roster includes premiere athletes such as Robinson Cano, Skylar Diggins, [Kevin Durant](http://hiphopdx.com/news/id.24246/title.jay-z-s-roc-nation-sports-to-sign-kevin-durant-), Geno Smith, Victor Cruz, CC Sabathia, James Young, Dez Bryant, Ndamukong Suh, Rusney Castillo, Yoenis Cespedes, Jaelen Strong, Todd Gurley, Wilson Chandler, Erick Aybar, Justise Winslow, Willie Cauley-Stein, [Jerome Boateng](http://hiphopdx.com/news/id.34855/title.jay-z-signs-soccer-player-jerome-boateng-to-roc-nation-sports#), Miguel Sano, CJ Prosise, Ronnie Stanley, Henry Ellenson, Caris LeVert and Mike Gbinije.

For full list of client: [(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roc_Nation_Sports#Clients)

Baseball

Erick Aybar, Atlanta Braves
Robinson Canó, Seattle Mariners
Rusney Castillo, Boston Red Sox
Yoenis Céspedes, New York Mets
D. J. Peterson, Seattle Mariners
Dustin Peterson, Atlanta Braves
CC Sabathia, New York Yankees
Braden Shipley, Arizona Diamondbacks

American Football

Dez Bryant, Dallas Cowboys
Victor Cruz, Chicago Bears
Todd Gurley, Los Angeles Rams
C. J. Prosise, Seattle Seahawks
Geno Smith, New York Giants
Ronnie Stanley, Baltimore Ravens
Jaelen Strong, Houston Texans
Ndamukong Suh, Miami Dolphins
Leonard Fournette, Jacksonville Jaguars

Basketball

Willie Cauley-Stein, Sacramento Kings
Wilson Chandler, Denver Nuggets
Skylar Diggins, Dallas Wings
Kevin Durant, Golden State Warriors
Henry Ellenson, Detroit Pistons
Michael Gbinije, Detroit Pistons
Caris LeVert, Brooklyn Nets
Justise Winslow, Miami Heat
James Young, Boston Celtics
Matt Barnes, Golden State Warriors
Rudy Gay, Sacramento Kings
Ty Lawson, Sacramento Kings

Association football

Jérôme Boateng, FC Bayern Munich

Boxing

Miguel Cotto
Andre Ward
Luis Arias
Sonny Fredrickson
Tyler McCreary

Retail

Malcolm Anderson, AT&T